# WindowBuilder Causes Content Assist Problem

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I have been troubling this problem for two days. When I click "." or Ctrl+Space Eclipse shows up this error (see screenshot). I got this error after installing WindowBuilder. I couldn't solve whatever I did. I am using eclipse version 4.17

[image: error message]

Comment: Had you tried disabling the plug-in as mentioned in the error dialog?

Comment: I tried disabling plug-in but still warns me. I get this message from .log file: java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "org.eclipse.wb.core.ui".

Comment: You get this error because the computing of the code completion proposals of [PDE API Tools](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-api-tools/) exceed a timeout. It is not caused by or related to WindowBuilder. In the preferences _Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced_ did you uncheck _API Tools Proposals_ or what you mean by _"I tried disabling plug-in"_? The real cause might be a plugin you installed in addition of missing keeping your Eclipse up to date.

Comment: Yes, I unchecked API Tools Proposals

Comment: Okey, I solved this error. I updated Eclipse then problem solved. Thank you all for responding